# ws-trust with wso2 php framework

Tags: php, wso2

Are there examples showing ws-trust and saml 2.0 usage with the wso2 php framework as I have to get a RSTR token from an https webservice and then consume that token and sign the request to talk to another service with the binarysecret symmetric key received in the RSTR token.

I can do everything without the library only generating the signature value with the received

`hash_hmac('sha1', $signedinfo, $secret,TRUE);`

Therefore want to go back to wso2 php framework or is there any other framework for this as most of the framework out there dont support this

Answer (score 0):

WSO2 WSF/PHP doesn't support SAML. You have to use an external PHP library to do this.